# Collatz Conjecture: What is the problem with this simple argument for showing there are no cycles

Tags: solution-verification, collatz-conjecture

I came across this argument related to the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).

It is clear to me that the argument cannot be valid.  It is too simple and if it were true, it would be widely known.

I have done my best to clean up the argument.  If any point is unclear or if there is a simpler way to make the same argument, let me know and I will be glad to revise.

What is the flaw?

**Let:**

- $C(x)$ be the collatz operation such that $C(x) = \dfrac{3x+1}{2^n}$ where $n$ is the highest power of $2$ that divides $3x+1$.
- $x>1, y\ge 1$ be distinct, odd integers such that $C(C(C(\dots C(x)\dots) = y$.
- $u_0, u_1, \dots, u_n$ be the intermediate results between $x$ and $y$ so that:

> $C(x) = u_n, C(u_n)=C(u_{n-1}), \dots, C(u_1) = u_0, C(u_0) = y$

**Claim:**

For any two distinct positive odd integers $x>1, y\ge 1$ where $C(C(C(\dots C(x)\dots) = y$, there are no repeated numbers in the sequence up to $y$.  That is, for all $i,j$:

- $u_i = u_j$ iff $i=j$
- $u_i \ne x$
- $u_i \ne y$

**Argument:**

(1)  We can assume that $x$ and $y$ will not appear as intermediate values.  That is, for $i$, $u_i \ne x$ and $u_i \ne y$.  If $x$ were an intermediate value before $y$, then $y$ could never be reached since $C(x)$ is a function and the same input will result in the same output.  If $y$ were an intermediate value, then we could end the sequence at that point.

Note:  The claim is not that $y$ doesn't repeat but that there are no repeats up to $y$.  For example, in the case where $y=1$, $C(y)=y$.  While there may be repeats after $y$, the claim is that there are no repeats before $y$.

(2)  It is clear that $y$ cannot be divisible by $3$ and further that $C(y)=y$ only if $y=1$

Clearly, $3 \nmid \dfrac{3x+1}{2^n}$ and $y \ne \dfrac{3y+1}{2^n}$ when $y \ne 1$

(3)  We can assume that $C(x) \ne y$.  If $C(x)=y$, then the argument is complete since $x$ and $y$ are distinct.

(4)  There exists a positive integer $w > 1$ distinct from $x,y$ where $C(w) = y$

(5)  Further, there are an infinite number of such $w_i$ where $C(w_i)=y$:

- Let $w_{i+1} = 4w_i + 1$
- Clearly, $C(w_{i+1}) = \dfrac{3w_{i+1} + 1}{2^n} = \dfrac{3(4w_i + 1) + 1}{2^n} = \dfrac{12w_i + 4}{2^n} = \dfrac{4(3w_i + 1)}{2^n} = \dfrac{3w_i + 1}{2^{n-2}}$
- Clearly, none of these $w_i = x$ since we assumed that $C(x) \ne y$ and $C(w_i) = y$  From our assumption at (1), none of these $w_i = y$

(6)  Assume that $C(x) \ne w$.  If $C(x)=w$, then the argument is complete since $x, w, y$ are distinct.

(7)  There exists a positive integer $v > 1$ distinct from $x, w$ such that $C(v) = w$. (Distinct from all $w_i$ above since $C(w) = y \ne w$)

Note:  Other observations:

- There are an infinite $v_i$ such that $C(v_i) = w_i$ for each $w_i$.  This is the same argument as (6).
- None of these $v_i = x$ and none of these $v_i = w_i$ and none of these $v_i = y$ since $C(y) \ne w$.  When $y \ne 1$, it is impossible that $C(y) = w$ since $C(w) = y$.  When $y=1$, it is not possible from the assumption in step(1).

> $y = \dfrac{3w_0 + 1}{2^n}$ so, clearly, $\dfrac{3\frac{3w_0 + 1}{2^n}+1}{2^m} = \dfrac{9w_0 + 3 + 2^n}{2^{n+m}} \ne w_0$

(8)  If we take $w,v,x,y$ as the base case, we can now assume that for any $x,y$ there exists a sequence of intermediate values $u_i$ such that $C(u_0) = y$, $C(u_1) = u_0$ and so on up until $u_n$ where $C(u_n) = C(u_{n-1})$.  All values are distinct.

(9)  To complete the argument, we need to show that there is necessarily $u_{n+1}$ that has the same properties.

(10)  From our original assumption, there exists $u_{n+1}$ such that $C(u_{n+1}) = u_n$.  We can further assume that $u_{n+1}$ is distinct from $x$.  Otherwise, the argument is already proven.

(11)  Because $C(u_{n+1}) = u_n$ and each $u_i$ is distinct from the others, it follows that $u_{n+1}$ is distinct from all $u_0, u_1, \dots u_n$.  Otherwise, $C(u_{n+1})$ wouldn't equal $u_n$.  To complete the argument, we just need to show that it is distinct from $y$ which is the case from our assumption in step(1).

Note:  Assume that $u_{n+1} = u_j$ where $j < u_{n+1}$, then $C(u_{n+1}) = C(u_j) = u_{j-1}$ but $C(u_{n+1}) = u_n$ and by assumption $u_n \ne u_{j-1}$ so we have a contradiction and can reject the assumption.

Comment: Your point (1) can be reduced to "let the sequence $u_1,u_2,...,u_n$ be the shortest possible sequence with the described property".  Otherwise that point looks like you are assuming something like your result.  It would be a good idea to collect a couple sequences that do repeat and run them through your assumption mill and see where it breaks.

Comment: Great point.  That sounds like the flaw.  So, if a cycle exists, the argument shows that within the cycle, it is pssible to find a subset that doesn"t repeat.  Now, I am clear.  :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The flaw is the statement

> We can assume that x and y will not appear as intermediate values. That is, for i, ui≠x and ui≠y. If x were an intermediate value before y, then y could never be reached since C(x) is a function and the same input will result in the same output. If y were an intermediate value, then we could end the sequence at that point.

This is only valid if you're actually trying prove the following statement:

> Suppose $y \neq x$ and that $n$ is the least $n \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $y = C^n(x)$ (where $C^n$ means applying $C$ $n$ times). Then there are no repeats in the sequence $x, C(x), C^2(x), ..., C^n(x)$.

This statement is always true (in fact, one doesn't even need to know anything about $C$ to prove that this is true). But it tells you absolutely nothing about the existence (or nonexistence) of cycles.

To illustrate this point, simply consider a "simplified version" where $C : \{0, 1\} \to \{0, 1\}$ is defined by $C(x) = 1 - x$. The statement above statement also holds when talking about this $C$, but clearly there is a $C$-cycle.